# Calculate rolling mean for each row in a data frame

Tags: r

For a data frame that looks like:

```
Value  Id
 1      xxx-rrr-ttt
 78     ggg-oop-rty
 97     fad-dar-oki
 ..      ..
 ..      ..
 ..      ..
```

I need to calculate the rolling-mean at each row. So for a data frame `s`, rolling mean at each row will be represented as `s.mean`. Is there any inbuilt function in `R` that can calculate `rolling-mean` ? I tried the following:

```
rollapply(data)
```

but it throws an error `argument "width" is missing, with no default`. I could not understand this error and what is meant by the `width`

Comment: You can use `rollmean` from `zoo`.  With `rollapply`, you need to pass the function and width argument.  You can check the documentation of `?rollapply` if there is doubt.  `width -  
numeric vector or list. In the simplest case this is an integer specifying the window width (in numbers of observations) which is aligned to the original sample according to the align argument. Alternatively, width can be a list regarded as offsets compared to the current time, see below for details.`

Comment: @akrun I have already imported the package, but not sure how to use the function.

Comment: @akrun Could you show with an example as an answer?

Comment: you probably need to pass a column name instead of complete dataframe. What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah No. It gives an error about width

Comment: @Jatt Please check the example I provided as a a solution

Comment: @downvoter Any reason?

Comment: @RonakShah How did you term it as duplicate? Any question related to `moving mean` cannot be a duplicate.

Comment: @Jatt I see no difference between the question you have asked and the one marked. If you would have read the documentation at `?rollmean` or `?rollapply` you would have got the answer yourself. Moreover, if you still think your question is different from the one marked please feel free to vote to reopen the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the same output with `rollmean` or `rollapply`

```
library(zoo)
rollmean(df1$Value, k = 3)
#[1]  0.13677590  0.12419375  0.22781866  0.17661827  0.51935576  0.08137071 -0.29009330 -0.43751774
rollapply(df1$Value, width = 3, FUN = mean)
#[1]  0.13677590  0.12419375  0.22781866  0.17661827  0.51935576  0.08137071 -0.29009330 -0.43751774
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Value = rnorm(10))
```

Comment: What is `3` in the rollmean and rollapply?

Comment: @Jatt  Updated the post

Comment: What does it mean by `width = 3`? I could not understand this. How did you come to 3?

Comment: @Jatt It is a example to show you that for 3 values, it does the rollling mean.  In your data, I am not sure what would be your rolling mean width.  Are you going to take the mean for every 2 values, 3 values?

Comment: Okay. I get it. Is there any way I could also calculate rolling-standard deviation?

Comment: @Jatt You can use `rollapply` and change `FUN` to `sd`  If you need a custom function, use `RcppRoll:roll_sd`

Comment: rollapply for `sd` worked fine!

Comment: Don't mean to extend this. Just wanted to ask you one last thing. To find data points that are more than (6*s.d.) away from mean, in the same data frame, does the following make sense `df[df$value > 6*df$sd + df$mean,]` ?

Comment: @Jatt  What is `4*` ?

Comment: Just removed it. It was a typo

Comment: Made it `6*df$sd`

Comment: I meant `df$mean - 6*df$sd`

Comment: Did not get the `abs` part?

Comment: I meant to say about mean + or -

Comment: Okay. `df[df$value > (6*df$sd + df$mean) | (df$mean - 6*df$sd),]` Does it make sense?

Comment: It should be wrapped with `abs` i.e. `abs((6*df$sd + df$mean) | (df$mean - 6*df$sd))`